# Почему метод some() возвращает false?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Почему мой предикат не останавливает выполнение метода some? Результат всегда false, хотя я ожидаю true.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

function include(searchInArr, searchElement) {
  return searchInArr.some((x) => {
    x == searchElement;
  });
}

console.log(include(arr, 2));
```

В документации сказано, что если хотя бы для одного элемента в массиве условие выполнится, немедленно вернется true.

В отладчике все элемента массива сравниваются с переданной цифрой но даже при (2 == 2) проверка продолжается и в конечном итоге возвращается false. Почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не возвращает результат сравнения:

```
function include(searchInArr, searchElement) {
  return searchInArr.some(x => {
    return x == searchElement;
  });
}
```

или короткая форма:

```
function include(searchInArr, searchElement) {
  return searchInArr.some(x => x == searchElement);
}
```